# Econnect Warning: Distributed Transaction was used

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, econnect

We just moved one of our apps which is a .net windows service to a new 2016 server in a different domain than the Microsoft GP database server is in.

We are using EConnect 14 (GP 2015).

We are getting 1000's of these warning in the application event log, which causes a problem because we use System Center and when it sees all those warnings it is spiking the CPU to process them.   They don't stop until we restart our windows service.

Here is the warning.

```
Distributed Transaction was used
This could be caused by new connection strings used within each xml document, but reusing the base transaction scope. 
Configuration Setting 'ReuseBaseTransaction' is by default FALSE. Remove this configuration setting, or set it to FALSE if this was not the expected behavior.
```

i've tried adding this into the econnect service config and my apps config,  tried setting it to false, tried true as well and the warning persists.

```
   <appSettings>
         <add key="ReuseBaseTransaction" value="false"/>
  </appSettings>
```

We are using the econnect windows service,  we are not bypassing the proxy and going directly to the stored procs.

Do you have any idea how to prevent this warning.  I really don't care if the transaction is distributed or not.     I found this related article but it offers no solution.

https://dynamicsgpland.blogspot.com/2010/09/econnect-2010-fills-event-log-with.html

as well as this one.
https://community.dynamics.com/gp/b/gpdynland/archive/2010/09/23/econnect-2010-fills-event-log-with-warning-34-distributed-transaction-was-used-34

-Randy

Answer (score 0):

There is a flag in the eConnect API that you can configure in your app.config in order to disable the logging of these promotions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <appSettings>
  <add key="LogDtcPromotions" value="false"/>
 </appSettings> 
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"  sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```